# Is it possible to save my Form Data into a database in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am putting my  forms on a  Wordpress page, and was wondering if it was possible to save the data in a database in Wordpress. Would this be possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it would be possible.

It entails using either WordPress core functions such as:

- [wp_insert_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post)
- [wp_insert_attachment](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment)

Or the WordPress DB class and writing your own SQL `INSERT` queries:

- [wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

In either case you need to add your own form processing logic -- taking form variables and organizing them into the correct parameters required by the WordPress post structure -- as well as your own access-control logic -- checking which user is submitting this form and if he is allowed to do so.